# Why can I not show my current_url with my detail_view?

Tags: python, django, url

I am a bit confused. I have a django app and I am trying to print out my current urls. Or better my current path of my website.

I have two views which I gave the names:

list_view (for listing all instances)
detail_view (for showing details of my instances)

On my main page I'd like to get the current path. I do that like that:

```
{% url 'detail_jobs' as detail %}
{% url 'list_jobs' as list %}

      {{ detail }}
      {{ list }}
```

```
My urls are: 

urlpatterns = [
    path('jobs', list_jobs, name="list_jobs"),
    path('jobs/<int:id>/', detail_view, name="detail_jobs"),

]
```

Now the {{list}} variable gives me back my current path, whereas the detail_view is giving me back nothing. Why? I don't get that....

I also have this function, which shouldn't interfere:

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("detail_jobs", kwargs={"id" : self.id})
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: `path('jobs/<int:id>/', detail_view, name="detail_jobs"),` this url pattern looks like you expect an argument for that url to resolve. I would expect, that `{% url 'list_jobs' 1 as list %}` would work.

Comment: This could would actually give you a NoReverseMatchError though.

Comment: it absolutely works brother!! You are right, it expects an argument, namely the id of the job. Now, is there a way to pass that in dynamically? I mean the id, so that if my path is /../../12 I can return that with argument 12?

Comment: {% url 'detail_jobs' detail.id as detail %}

Comment: works like a charm mate!! Thank so much everyone!